# Copying multiple conditional formats of an entire row to the rest of the spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

This seems like a very simple task, but it is so hard to figure out.
I have one row that has a format to find the max number. That row also has a format to find duplicates. How can I copy those formats from the one row to the res of the rows in the spreadsheet in mass without doing row by row (it is 393 rows)

Answer (score 1):

I've done this where I select the first formatted row, then use Format Painter and select the next row. Your format is now applied to 2 rows. Then select those 2 rows, and use Format Painter on the next 2 rows. Now you have 4 rows formatted. Double each time, and you'll reach 393 rows in 10 steps.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer will work, but there is a more direct, single step way.

Select the cells in the row (do not just select the whole row, just what you need) that have the formats you need. For instance:

1. Perhaps the cells are right next to each other, in the way cells B1 and C1 are right next to each other. If so, just select those two cells.
2. Perhaps the cells are NOT right next to each other, in the way cells B1 and W1 are not next to each other. If so, select the one of them and do what I describe next. Then select the other one and do it for that one.

So, you have the cells, whichever ones you need, selected. Copy them to the Windows Clipboard, perhaps with Ctrl-C or right-clicking with the mouse and choosing Copy. Next, click in the cells right below and select all the way down as far as you need. In your case, that seems to be about row 393 or 394 or so. Once they are all selected, press the key combination `Alt-E`, then the `S` key. Or right-click with the mouse and find `Paste Special` about a third of the way down on the menu that pops up. Whichever way you do it, a dialog box pops up that is titled `Paste Special`.

Immediately below the title is the word `Paste`. Immediately below that word is a list of things, all having a bullet circle on its left side. You can click in the circles and a black dot will appear in them when you do. The third option down the list is `Formats`.

Click its empty circle and notice the black dot appear. Press `Enter` or click OK and it will happen.

What happens? You are pasting the formats the cell or cells you copied have in them. Not just the "regular" ones you get from normal formatting, but also ALL Conditional Formats that have been applied to them. But no values or formulas were pasted:  the cell contents have not changed, only their formatting. Mind you, if the formatting is much different than it was to start, it might LOOK like values changed, but really only their DISPLAY changed, not the values or formulas themselves.

And that's it. You've done it.

You can make the process a wee bit easier on yourself. Once you've copied the already formatted cell, you can use the complete keyboard combination of `Alt-S-T` or when you right-click, just above that line that you clicked that said `Paste Special`, are a row of five buttons. The fourth from the left is one that has a paint brush on it. If you click it, you do the same thing with the click that the full keyboard shortcut combination does, or the way I first presented. No box pops up, it just does it.